# Having issues in getting pgAdmin4 working on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel7, pgadmin-4

I am trying to install pgadmin 4 on an RHEL 7.5 EC2 instance and get it working. I refered to following link for installation step -

https://askubuntu.com/a/831263

in config.py I have changed the DEFAULT_SERVER= my-instance-ip

After executing the pgAdmin4.py script, it shows a message that tells me to navigate to http://my-instance-ip:5050

However when I try to open the page it says 'This site can’t be reached'
I have checked the security group, checked if the port 5050 is opened in the instance. Still it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firewall settings? is port 5050 opened to the internet?

Comment: Hi @n33rma found the issue, 5050 isn't opened  to the interne. Running the application of different port now. Thanks :)